# How to pass updated input value?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an input field with a value. I am trying to capture new text added to that input and pass it as the value to another input. Each time I pass it however, it is the old value that is passed. I realise it is probably a simple error I am making, but I can't seem to get it working although I have tried many times with different approaches. I am trying to do this using the [Zurb Joyride](http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin) plugin. So, the first input is within a step on the walkthrough and is to be passed to an input on the page itself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the stripped down code:

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="egText" value="Stuff" />
<a href="#" onclick="addText()" class="btn">Button</a>
<input type="text" id="searchBox" placeholder="A placeholder" />
```

JS

```
function addText() {
    var text = $("#egText").val();
    $("#searchBox").val(text);
}
```

jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Figlen/zyapmc7h/

Comment: how  are you updating the value  of the input field?

Comment: Just text input from a user.

Comment: Can you add the jsFiddle link you started to your question?

Comment: I used you exact code and it seems to be working. Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/saumil_sss/u1d3zLt8/

Comment: Works fine if you load your JavaScript in the proper place. See http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zyapmc7h/7/. You had it loading in the onload event which affects the scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('.btn').on('click', function(){
    var text = $("#egText").val();
    $("#searchBox").val(text);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g8uuL6a7/

I've included the fiddle, it's best practice not to use inline functions.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I changed my jsfiddle as advised by @Saumil Soni & @j08691 and I have changed my code to remove the inline function:

`$(window).load(function() {
  
  $("#AF_joyride").joyride({ 
    autoStart : true,
  });

  $('.addText a').on('click', function(){
      var text = $("#egText").val();
      $("#searchBox").val(text);

  }); 

});`

But I find that it is always the older, initial value that is passed, not the new one.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle and added an event handler to detect click instead of executing via a function

[**Here is the fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/saumil_sss/zyapmc7h/9/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
        var text = $("#egText").val();
        $("#searchBox").val(text);    
    });
});
```

Your link should have `id="myBtn"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses, but the issue I had (that the updated input val was not being passed) turns out to be due to the way Zurb Joyride works. To create it you set up an ol with the li being the steps of the joyride/walkthough. The Joyride JS then creates a new set of divs based on the list items. The id of #egText was then in the page twice, messing up the setting of the value. Using

var text = $(this).parent().find('#egText').val();

fixes it.

Thanks.